# Aggregation on GeoDjango queries

Tags: django, aggregation, geodjango

I have the following models:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class Shop(models.Model):
    objects = geomodels.GeoManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

class ShopOutlets(models.Model):
    objects = geomodels.GeoManager()
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    location  = geomodels.PointField(srid = 4326, blank = True, null = True)
```

What I am trying to do is find (distinct) Shops in order of their closest outlets to a given point.

I have tried this:

```
Shop.objects.annotate(dist = Min('shopoutlet__location'))
```

but it doesn't actually give me the option of specifying a center point.  Any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the distance between two points.

If you want this, just do:

```
ShopOutlets.objects.distance(point).order_by('distance')
```

[The distance method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance) will calculate the distance between your object to the given point, and will put a distance attr in your object dynamically.